Is there a way to see who ran a manual stage in an ADO YAML pipeline?
Me and my team are trying to utilize the somewhat recently added manual stages in our YAML piplines. We would like to use them for our production deployments that we don't want automated.
Our issue is that we need to know who manually started the production stage for auditing purposes, but cannot seem to find any way to do this either through the UI, pipeline variables, or APIs (looking at timeline record, builds, pipeline runs).
Can this information be found anywhere and if so, how do I find it?

There is no method to get who manually runs the stage in a run of YAML pipeline. the current available methods (API/CLI and predefined variables) can only get who triggers/queues the pipeline run.
If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on Developer Community.
This will make it more convenient for the Azure DevOps engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

